# Chat server plugin API for J2EE web application

Tags: java, web-services, chat, mobile-application

I need to build a Mobile App (iOS, Android, Windows all) that has a chat functionality. Registered users can chat among themselves. At back-end, there is a J2EE based web application (web-services) to which Mobile-Apps talk (SOA/REST).
**How can I plugin a Chat Server application into the web application**, to which all mobile apps can connect ? Please suggest if there are any API available.

Comment: The functionality I need to implement is similar to [quickblox](http://quickblox.com/modules/chat/)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some of the APIs and RTC Applications that one can explore.

1. [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) - Open-source, JSF
2. [JWebSocket](https://jwebsocket.org) - Open-source, Java/JavaScript based, HTML5 WebSocket
3. [OpenFire](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire) - Open-source, XMPP Protocol

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for framework that would help you integrating a chat functionality so there is some known Framwork like [PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org)   which is Component based Framework for web and mobile application based on top of JSF , it include the chat feature ,it use inside the [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) framework for  realtime communication between client and server . check [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/chat.xhtml) Primefaces demo.